# Is there any alternative for background-attachment: fixed for horizontal scroll website?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to apply background-attachment: fixed on my website (horizontal scroll), but it did not seem work well, whereas it works just well on vertical scroll website.

Answer (score 0):

make `background-position:` with repeat mode it works well for horizontal scrolling websites

```
.myClass {
background-image:url(myimg.png);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position: -5px 5px; /* Any percentage or pixel value you want or you can use center top etc.*/
}
```

Comment: I tried this, it just changes the background position, what I want is same exact behavior as background-attachment: fixed.

Comment: then post some code. so that some one can find a solution for it